# WebDriver.io: Is there a way to excute steps before or after certain `it` blocks

Tags: hook, webdriver-io

I would like to execute the same set of steps **after** two particular `it` blocks (localised `after` hooks).

Hooks would run those steps at the start of the entire test suite or at the end, whereas I would like to focus on two particular `it` blocks.

I believe this is possible in RSpec; is there a way in WebDriver.io?

Answer (score 2):

you can use a describe function to wrap your two specs, like this:

```js
describe('your main describe',function(){
  describe('your localised describe',function(){
    before(function(){})
    
    it('spec 1',function(){})
    it('spec 2',function(){})
    
    after(function(){})
  })
})
```